# iOS Progress bar custom maximum and minimum values

Tags: ios, swift

I have Label in my UIView which continuously changes values in between 80(min) to 475(Max) now I have run the progress bar status with respect to max and min value of label continuously. below where the code i have tried till now

```
 if ampsMaxValue <= 80
        {
            ampsMaxValue              =  80
            ampsLabel.text            =  String(ampsMaxValue)
            ampsprogressBar.progress  =  Float(0)
            return
        }

        ampsMaxValue                =    ampsMaxValue - 1
        ampsLabel.textColor         =    UIColor.white
        ampsprogressBar.tintColor   =    UIColor.red
        ampsLabel.text = String(ampsMaxValue)
        v    -=   0.1
        ampsprogressBar.progress  =   Float(v)

    }else{

        if ampsMaxValue >= 475
        {
            ampsMaxValue    =  475
            ampsLabel.text  =  String(ampsMaxValue)
            ampsprogressBar.progress  =   Float(1)
            return;
        }

        ampsMaxValue                       =    ampsMaxValue + 1
        ampsLabel.textColor                =    UIColor.white
        ampsprogressBar.tintColor          =    UIColor.red

        ampsLabel.text = String(ampsMaxValue)
        v    +=   0.1
        ampsprogressBar.progress  =  Float(v)

    }
```

I was able show the increased and decreased value by 0.1, but not solved it.  need info about how calculate the exact increased and decreased value for the progress bar with respect to the label max an min value.

Comment: Just an advice, but *please*, for the sake of your future co-workers, do not format your code like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
v = (ampsMaxValue - 80) / (475 - 80)
```